# Battery case melting

Tags: ford, battery

I have a 2004 Ford Expedition, I have noticed that around the battery post on the negative terminal, that the case of the battery seems to be melting. I have noticed a lot of corrosive build-up on the negative battery terminal I have cleaned this. Now would these issues cause the check charging system warning alarm and light to come on?

[image]

Comment: The battery melting is due to excessive heat generated by (probably) a poor ohmic connection to the negative terminal by the flying lead.

Comment: Your question probably belongs on another stackexchange site but yes, this is likely a visible indication of abnormalities with the way that battery charges, holds charge and releases charge and would cause the onboard diagnostics to give you a check engine light once it detects that issue.

Comment: That battery (at least) is unreliable... get a new one, reset any dash fault codes, and you'll likely be back in business.